# How to put a div next to each other without it going below?

Tags: html, css

I'm tring to make an online game and I've spent quite some time trying to figure out how to do this (I'm using latest bootstrap). I've provided a pic. In it as you can see the "card" displays below and i need it to display below the navbar and on the right of the "stats" section. The server, stats and the card are all divs. I tried using fixed: left; on stats. float: left; on Servers. The card has float: right;

Just pointing out that the nav bar as well as the stats and servers is on a php header page and the card is separate on the main index.php.

If someone can help me fix this that would be amazing, I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

[Pic of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp50O.png)

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Here are the code snippets
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgja2.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp50O.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDvY5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnyxV.png

Comment: You basically need to show some effort what you did so far, for example, what is the current status of the coding. Paste them so that others can take a look for you.

Comment: Code should be as real code and in the question.

Comment: Viral, please don't post links to images of code, put the code in text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the Divs, you need to target them with CSS and set their display model to inline, see below

So for example, if you have 2 divs like so;

```
<div class="myinlinediv" id="content">
 Div 1
</div>

<div class="myinlinediv" id="sidebar">
 Div 2
</div>
```

In your CSS you would put

```
.myinlinediv {
 display: inline-block; /*This is the important line*/
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

This is an example with your code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="width:20%; display: inline-block;" class="card m1-2 mb-2 mt-2">
<div style="height:2.5em;" class="card-header">
Servers:
</div><!-- end card-header block -->
<div><!-- start list -->
<ul class="d-flex align-items-stretch list-group list-group-flush">
<li class="list-group-item">Username</li>
<li class="list-group-item">IP</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Money</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Attacks</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- end list -->
</div><!-- end card block -->

<div style="width:20%; display: inline-block;" class="card m1-2 mb-2 mt-2">
<div style="height:2.5em;" class="card-header">
Stats
</div> <!-- end card header -->
<div><!-- start list -->
<ul class="d-flex align-items-stretch list-group list-group-flush">
<li class="list-group-item">Username</li>
<li class="list-group-item">IP</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Money</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Attacks</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- end list -->
</div><!-- end card block -->


<div style=" width: 50%; margin-top:10px; display: inline-block;" class="card">
<div class="card-body">
This is some text within a card body.
This is some text within a card body.
This is some text within a card body.
This is some text within a card body.
</div><!-- end card body block -->
</div><!-- end div card block -->
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` take all of the with of the page, you can see that on the navigator's console.

You need to know the diference between **block** and **inline** elemenst of html.

`<Div>` is a block element and `<span>` is an inline element.

I recommend you read this articles:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

**Another thing:** if you wanna to get better your view of your webpage, you only need to learn **html5**, **css3**, and **javascript.** **PHP** is a lenguage sever and it is for different purpose, like conect to database or make a session.